# Upvalues of modified system functions

Tags: packages, system, upvalues

Suppose that someone (e.g. the author of a package I need to use) modifies
the upvalues of a system function in the following way

```
Unprotect[Series];
Series /: Series[x_foo, rest__] := mySeries[x, rest]
Protect[Series];
```

So that evaluating

```
Series[foo[ep], {ep, 0, 2}]
```

yields

```
mySeries[foo[ep], {ep, 0, 2}]
```

Now I'd like to modify some of these definitions without modifying the source code of a package.

Normally I would do this by loading the original package and then running some patching code that 
modifies the relevant up- and downvalues introduced by the package. However, in this case this doesn't
seem to be possible, as

```
UpValues[Series]
```

returns an empty list. So I'm wondering where these custom upvalues are saved and if there is a way to retrieve them?

P.S. I'm not advocating tampering with system functions, but there are packages (such as this [one](https://hypexp.hepforge.org/)) that do this kind of stuff and have no analogues, so that one simply has to use them for the relevant calculations. I'm not the author of the package, so I'm in no position to fix the code and redistribute it to my colleagues (even privately). Loading the original package and applying custom patching code (that everyone can inspect) afterwards is the best solution so far.

Comment: Try ```GeneralUtilities`Definitions[Series]```

Comment: `UpValues` are attached to the symbol *on* which you want the override the other one, which is what makes them a local and reasonably safe method to override functions. In your example, they should've been attached to `foo`: `UpValues[foo]`. But what you did was not adding `UpValues` - you actually added `DownValues` for `Series`, even though you used `TagSetDelayed`. To add `UpValues` for `foo`, you should've done  `foo /: Series[x_foo, rest__] := mySeries[x, rest]`, and in that case, it would also not be necessary to `Unprotect` the `Series` symbol.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin For `foo /: Series[x_foo, ...]` I agree. But here we have `Series/: Series[x_foo,...]` so `UpValues[foo]` returns an empty list.
 
As I have already stated in the question, it is not my code and I wouldn't have done it this way.

Comment: @vsht See my updated comment - you have actually created a `DownValue` for `Series`, rather than `UpValue` for `foo`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Ahh, now I see. The syntax is confusing but this makes sense. Very good, this solves my problem of patching the given package in a meaningful way. If you make your comment to an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: @vsht Ok, I posted the answer are requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Why it did not work

`UpValues` are attached to the symbol *on which* you want the override the other one, which is what makes them a local and reasonably safe method to override functions. In your example, they should've been attached to `foo`: `UpValues[foo]`. But what you did was not adding `UpValues` - you actually added `DownValues` for `Series`, even though you used `TagSetDelayed`.

#### `UpValues` and `TagSetDelayed`

It may be an important point to emphasize: the use of `TagSetDelayed` ***does not guarantee*** the creation of `UpValues` - rather, `TagSetDelayed` is a more general (w.r.t. say `SetDelayed`) construct which can create different kinds of definitions - depending on where the symbol that is used as a tag, is found in the definition being created.

OTOH, `TagSetDalayed` is generally more specific / precise than `UpSetDelayed`, since the latter will attach `UpValues` to all symbols which are at the right level on the l.h.s. of the definition, while the former only attaches definition to a single symbol / tag that one specifies. Which is why `TagSetDalayed` is usually a preferred way to attach `UpValues` to a symbol.

#### The correct form

To add `UpValues` for `foo`, you should've done

```
foo /: Series[x_foo, rest__] := mySeries[x, rest]
```

and in that case, it would also not be necessary to `Unprotect` the `Series` symbol.