# Is it a good idea to unprotect standard commands?

Tags: scoping

I often see in code by other people some standard functions like `Sum`, `NonCommutativeMultiply` etc get unprotected, supplemented by additional rules and then protected back. It is not clear to be that this is a good idea. How can I be sure that I will not mess up badly redefining something like `Sum`? Is not there a way to somehow clone the command say "`mySum=Sum`" and then make changes to the new command? Or maybe there is a way to modify an existing command locally, say within some scoping construct?

Comment: If you don't know what sort of consequences it could have, I recommend against it. In principle, there's no problem with modification of many built-in symbols, but some of them are crucial to the workings of the language. You can use ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` to temporarily change built-in functions without permanent damage: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25769/43522

Comment: There are many similar questions e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/218465/58370).

Comment: I echo what @Sjoerd said, and add that sometimes you want to alter the internal workings.  For instance, I wanted to place a [time limit on `Integrate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120650/4999) inside `DSolve` or [to change the `Method` of `Solve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63676/4999) inside `DSolve`. The alternative is that *Mathematica* fails. In their limited use-cases, altering built-ins seem worth the risk. But there is a risk.

Comment: One reason that functions are protected is to warn users who don't yet fully understand Mathematica syntax when their definitions are modifying built-in functions. A question to ask yourself, is my redefinition likely to be triggered in internal code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to unprotect standard commands?

No, it is not usually a good idea to modify built-ins. If you modify a built-in, other built-ins (or packages) that rely on it may either break or may slow down significantly. Here's an example of such a slowdown:

- [How can I speed up image importing?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1495/12)

If you are just looking to overload a built-in for your own custom expression type, consider using up-values instead.

Of course, there are some built-ins which are designed to be extended, e.g. `MakeBoxes`. That's an entirely different situation. You may also want to [intercept the calls to some functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39711/12) to better understand how the system works. That is also a reasonable application. However, if you were to publish a package in which you overload a fundamental function such as `Sum`, I would think twice before using your package.

> Is not there a way to somehow clone the command say "`mySum=Sum`" and then make changes to the new command?

You don't need to "clone" it. Simply use `Sum` in the definition of `mySum`.

Comment: Just to clarify. If I want to take standard `NonCommutativeMultiply` and then make it do whatever I want, I can just initialize `myNCM[x___]:=NonCommutativeMultiply[x]` and then do with `myNCM` whatever I want?

Comment: @WeatherReport No. `NonCommutativeMultiply` does not do anything, so there is no point to calling it from another function. `NonCommutativeMultiply` is one of those symbols which is meant to be given a definition (it does not have one by default). Just use it.